# How to add chart data in Open XML C# for Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Am trying to change data for an already existing word file. I've had success in manipulating data in embedded Excel file, but somehow, this data is not being used in Word file. Moreover, in Excel file, I see the green marker before the last row, probably signifying that the last row is still not being considered for the data. Can someone please help in handling the issue?

I did referred to lot of links from ericwhite.com / openxmldeveloper.org but had no luck.

The code is below:

```
    public void ReplaceChartValues(string placeholderCaption, System.Data.DataTable chartData, string newCaption)
    {
        if (wordDocument != null)
        {
            try
            {
                ChartPart target = mainDocumentPart
                    .ChartParts
                    .Where(r => r
                        .ChartSpace
                        .GetFirstChild<Chart>()
                        .Title
                        .InnerText
                        .StartsWith(placeholderCaption)
                    )
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (target != null)
                {
                    target
                        .ChartSpace
                        .GetFirstChild<Chart>()
                        .Title
                        .ChartText
                        .RichText
                        .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>()
                        .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run>()
                        .Text
                        .Text = newCaption;

                    ExternalData externalData =
                        target
                        .ChartSpace
                        .Elements<ExternalData>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (externalData != null)
                    {
                        EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart =
                            (EmbeddedPackagePart)
                            target
                            .Parts
                            .Where(r => r.RelationshipId == externalData.Id)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            .OpenXmlPart;

                        if (embeddedPackagePart != null)
                        {
                            using (Stream stream = embeddedPackagePart.GetStream())
                            {
                                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
                                {
                                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet worksheet = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet)spreadsheetDocument
                                        .WorkbookPart
                                        .Workbook
                                        .Sheets
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)
                                        spreadsheetDocument
                                        .WorkbookPart
                                        .Parts
                                        .Where(r => r.RelationshipId == worksheet.Id)
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .OpenXmlPart;

                                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData sheetData =
                                        worksheetPart
                                        .Worksheet
                                        .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData>()
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                                    var existingRows = sheetData
                                        .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>()
                                        .Skip(1)
                                        .ToArray();

                                    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < existingRows.Length; ctr++)
                                    {
                                        sheetData
                                            .RemoveChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>(existingRows[ctr]);
                                    }

                                    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chartData.Rows.Count; ctr++)
                                    {
                                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRecord = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                                        for (int ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < chartData.Columns.Count; ctr2++)
                                        {
                                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell newCell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue newCellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue();

                                            if (chartData.Columns[ctr2].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                                            {
                                                newCellValue.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(chartData.Rows[ctr][ctr2]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                                newCell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Date;
                                            }
                                            else if (chartData.Columns[ctr2].DataType == typeof(decimal))
                                            {
                                                newCellValue.Text = chartData.Rows[ctr][ctr2].ToString();
                                                newCell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                newCellValue.Text = chartData.Rows[ctr][ctr2].ToString();
                                                newCell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                                            }
                                            newCell.AppendChild(newCellValue);

                                            newRecord.AppendChild(newCell);
                                        }

                                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRecord);
                                    }

                                    spreadsheetDocument.Save();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // Save the document.
                mainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Embedded Excel not considering last line]

Comment: Not sure why the question was down-voted... Some reference should have been provided before downvoting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent lot of hours behind this and here is the code that helped:

```
    public void ReplaceChartValuesLinearChart(string placeholderCaption, System.Data.DataTable chartData, string newCaption)
    {
        if (wordDocument != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the exact Chart Part where Caption matches the place holder value.
                ChartPart target = mainDocumentPart
                    .ChartParts
                    .Where(r => r
                        .ChartSpace
                        .GetFirstChild<Chart>()
                        .Title
                        .InnerText
                        .StartsWith(placeholderCaption)
                    )
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (target != null)
                {
                    // Set the new caption.
                    target
                        .ChartSpace
                        .GetFirstChild<Chart>()
                        .Title
                        .ChartText
                        .RichText
                        .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>()
                        .GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run>()
                        .Text
                        .Text = newCaption;

                    // Update all NumberingCache values to reflect total number of records.
                    foreach (NumberingCache currentNumberingCache in target.ChartSpace.Descendants<NumberingCache>())
                    {
                        currentNumberingCache.PointCount = new PointCount() { Val = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value)(UInt32)chartData.Rows.Count };
                        currentNumberingCache.RemoveAllChildren<NumericPoint>();
                    }

                    // Set the Numeric Point values with formats and add to the appropriate NumberingCache.
                    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chartData.Rows.Count; ctr++)
                    {
                        // First Range - contains date.
                        NumericPoint newNumericPoint = new NumericPoint();
                        newNumericPoint.Index = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value((uint)ctr);
                        newNumericPoint.FormatCode = "[$-409]ddmmmyyyy";
                        newNumericPoint.NumericValue = new NumericValue(chartData.Rows[ctr][0].ToString());
                        target
                            .ChartSpace
                            .Descendants<NumberingCache>()
                            .ToArray()[0]
                            .AppendChild(newNumericPoint);

                        // Third Range - contains date.
                        newNumericPoint = new NumericPoint();
                        newNumericPoint.Index = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value((uint)ctr);
                        newNumericPoint.FormatCode = "[$-409]ddmmmyyyy";
                        newNumericPoint.NumericValue = new NumericValue(chartData.Rows[ctr][0].ToString());
                        target
                            .ChartSpace
                            .Descendants<NumberingCache>()
                            .ToArray()[2]
                            .AppendChild(newNumericPoint);

                        // Second Range - contains reference data.
                        if (chartData.Rows[ctr][2] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            newNumericPoint = new NumericPoint();
                            newNumericPoint.Index = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value((uint)ctr);
                            newNumericPoint.FormatCode = "0.00%";
                            newNumericPoint.NumericValue = new NumericValue(chartData.Rows[ctr][2].ToString());
                            target
                                .ChartSpace
                                .Descendants<NumberingCache>()
                                .ToArray()[1]
                                .AppendChild(newNumericPoint);
                        }

                        // Second Range - contains current data.
                        if (chartData.Rows[ctr][3] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            newNumericPoint = new NumericPoint();
                            newNumericPoint.Index = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value((uint)ctr);
                            newNumericPoint.FormatCode = "0.00%";
                            newNumericPoint.NumericValue = new NumericValue(chartData.Rows[ctr][3].ToString());
                            target
                                .ChartSpace
                                .Descendants<NumberingCache>()
                                .ToArray()[3]
                                .AppendChild(newNumericPoint);
                        }
                    }

                    // Update all variable length formula to point to updated number of rows.
                    foreach (var currentFormula in target.ChartSpace.Descendants<Formula>())
                    {
                        if (currentFormula.Text.Contains(":"))
                        {
                            currentFormula.Text =
                                currentFormula.Text.Substring(0, currentFormula.Text.LastIndexOf("$") + 1)
                                + (chartData.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    // Get handle to ExternalData for accessing embedded Excel document.
                    ExternalData externalData =
                        target
                        .ChartSpace
                        .Elements<ExternalData>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (externalData != null)
                    {
                        // Get handle to Package Part containing excel document.
                        EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart =
                            (EmbeddedPackagePart)
                            target
                            .Parts
                            .Where(r => r.RelationshipId == externalData.Id)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            .OpenXmlPart;

                        if (embeddedPackagePart != null)
                        {
                            // Get handle to Stream for modifying data.
                            using (Stream stream = embeddedPackagePart.GetStream())
                            {
                                // Open Excel for manipulation.
                                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = 
                                    SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
                                {
                                    // Get handle to first sheet.
                                    DocumentFormat
                                        .OpenXml
                                        .Spreadsheet
                                        .Sheet worksheet = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet)
                                            spreadsheetDocument
                                            .WorkbookPart
                                            .Workbook
                                            .Sheets
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

                                    // Get handle to first worksheet.
                                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)
                                        spreadsheetDocument
                                        .WorkbookPart
                                        .Parts
                                        .Where(r => r.RelationshipId == worksheet.Id)
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .OpenXmlPart;

                                    // Set Table range on the first worksheet.
                                    worksheetPart
                                        .TableDefinitionParts
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .Table
                                        .Reference
                                        .Value = "A1:D" + (chartData.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();

                                    // Get handle to access entire sheet data.
                                    DocumentFormat
                                        .OpenXml
                                        .Spreadsheet
                                        .SheetData sheetData =
                                            worksheetPart
                                            .Worksheet
                                            .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

                                    // Select all data rows.
                                    var existingRows = sheetData
                                        .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>()
                                        .Skip(1)
                                        .ToArray();

                                    // Remove all existing data rows.
                                    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < existingRows.Length; ctr++)
                                    {
                                        sheetData
                                            .RemoveChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>(existingRows[ctr]);
                                    }

                                    // Create new rows.
                                    for (int ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < chartData.Rows.Count; ctr1++)
                                    {
                                        DocumentFormat
                                            .OpenXml
                                            .Spreadsheet
                                            .Row newRecord = new 
                                                DocumentFormat
                                                .OpenXml
                                                .Spreadsheet.Row();

                                        // Set values and formats for each cell for new row.
                                        for (int ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < chartData.Columns.Count; ctr2++)
                                        {
                                            // Create a new cell.
                                            DocumentFormat
                                                .OpenXml
                                                .Spreadsheet
                                                .Cell newCell = new 
                                                    DocumentFormat
                                                    .OpenXml
                                                    .Spreadsheet
                                                    .Cell();

                                            // Create a new cell value for holding actual value of the cell.
                                            DocumentFormat
                                                .OpenXml
                                                .Spreadsheet
                                                .CellValue newCellValue = new 
                                                    DocumentFormat
                                                    .OpenXml
                                                    .Spreadsheet
                                                    .CellValue();

                                            // Set appropriate Style, Data Type and value for the cell.
                                            switch (ctr2)
                                            {
                                                case 0:
                                                    newCell.StyleIndex = new 
                                                            DocumentFormat
                                                            .OpenXml
                                                            .UInt32Value((uint)2);
                                                    newCellValue.Text = 
                                                        chartData.Rows[ctr1][ctr2].ToString();
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:

                                                    newCellValue.Text = 
                                                        GetSharedStringIndex(
                                                                spreadsheetDocument
                                                                .WorkbookPart
                                                                .SharedStringTablePart, 
                                                                chartData.Rows[ctr1][ctr2].ToString());
                                                    newCell.StyleIndex = new 
                                                        DocumentFormat
                                                        .OpenXml
                                                        .UInt32Value((uint)2);
                                                    newCell.DataType = 
                                                            DocumentFormat
                                                            .OpenXml
                                                            .Spreadsheet
                                                            .CellValues
                                                            .SharedString;
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                case 3:
                                                    newCellValue.Text = 
                                                        chartData.Rows[ctr1][ctr2].ToString();

                                                    if (chartData.Rows[ctr1][ctr2] != DBNull.Value && 
                                                        chartData.Rows[ctr1][ctr2].ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        newCell.StyleIndex = new 
                                                            DocumentFormat
                                                            .OpenXml
                                                            .UInt32Value((uint)3);
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        newCell.StyleIndex = new 
                                                            DocumentFormat
                                                            .OpenXml
                                                            .UInt32Value((uint)1);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                            }

                                            // Append newly created cell value to the cell.
                                            newCell.AppendChild(newCellValue);

                                            // Append newly created cell to the Row.
                                            newRecord.AppendChild(newCell);
                                        }

                                        // Append newly created row to the Excel sheet.
                                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRecord);
                                    }

                                    spreadsheetDocument.Save();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // Save the document.
                mainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetSharedStringIndex(SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTablePart, string valueToSearch)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        // Return index if item already exists.
        foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SharedStringItem currentItem in sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (currentItem.InnerText == valueToSearch)
            {
                return counter.ToString();
            }
            counter++;
        }

        // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index.
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(valueToSearch)));
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        return counter.ToString();
    }
```